# Unable to install Rmagick on CentOS - ImageMagick is installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, centos, rmagick

I am having difficulty installing the rmagick gem on CentOS. I am getting the following error

```
$ gem install rmagick
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/home/bn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for gcc... yes
checking for Magick-config... yes
checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... yes
checking for HDRI disabled version of ImageMagick... yes
checking for stdint.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/home/bn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby
/home/bn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': 
The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
from /home/bn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:506:in `try_cpp'
from /home/bn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:931:in `block in have_header'
from /home/bn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
from /home/bn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
from /home/bn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
from /home/bn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
from /home/bn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
from /home/bn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
from /home/bn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
from /home/bn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:930:in `have_header'
from extconf.rb:194:in `<main>'
```

ImageMagick is definitely installed

```
$ which convert
/usr/bin/convert
```

Other compiled gems such as nokogiri install without issue.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You may need ImageMagick-devel: `yum install ImageMagick-devel`

Comment: ImageMagick-devel is also installed.  

`Package matching ImageMagick-devel-6.5.4.7-6.el6_2.x86_64 already installed.`

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment was wrong. You are missing /usr/include/stdint.h which is provided by the package `glibc-headers`. This is an indirect dependence of `gcc`. Have you installed gcc using yum?

Comment: I was able to solve the problem by downgrading ImageMagick from the most recent version to the previous one. If anyone needs the exact version numbers, I can look them up.